# Swing - JTable cell highlight with different Colors

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a textbox with search button, if i click on search text, String gets highlighted in JTable cells, if the search text is having multiple Strings with comma separated, all those comma separated Strings has to be displayed in a different colors dynamically.

Can you please suggest what changes i need to do to the below working code(single String highlight)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import java.awt.*;

public class TableExample {
    JFrame f;
    private JTextField textField; 

    TableExample() {
        f = new JFrame();
        String data[][] = {{"101", "lala", "670000"}, {"101", "lala", "670000"}, {"102", "Jai", "780000"},
                {"101", "Sachin", "700000"}};
        String column[] = {"ID", "NAME", "SALARY"};
        JTable jt = new JTable();
        jt.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt); 

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, column); 
        dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(column);
        jt.setModel(dtm);

        JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
        inputpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputpanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        textField = new JTextField();
        JButton button = new JButton("Highlight");

        button.addActionListener(e -> { 
            jt.repaint();
        });

        inputpanel.add(textField);
        inputpanel.add(button);
        jt.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CellHighlightRenderer()); 

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, inputpanel, sp);

        f.add(splitPane);
        f.setSize(300, 400);
    }
    class CellHighlightRenderer extends JTextField implements TableCellRenderer {
        public DefaultHighlighter high = new DefaultHighlighter();
        public DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlight_painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(
                Color.YELLOW);

        public CellHighlightRenderer() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            setHighlighter(high);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                                       int row, int column) {

            setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
            setForeground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionForeground() : table.getForeground());

            setFont(table.getFont());
            setValue(value);
            int pos = 0;
            String pattern = textField.getText(); // Grab the text.
            if (pattern != null && pattern.trim().length() > 0)
                while ((pos = value.toString().indexOf(pattern, pos)) >= 0) {
                    try {
                        high.addHighlight(pos, pos + pattern.length(), highlight_painter);
                        pos += pattern.length();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            return this;
        }

        protected void setValue(Object value) {
            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            TableExample te = new TableExample();
            te.f.setVisible(true); 
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done what i think you asked. Read commends inside the code. Whenever u see a comment, try to compare it with your code. I didnt know what colors you want so i have done with random color to each word.

Preview:

[image]

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;

public class TableExample {
    JFrame f;
    private JTextField textField; // make the textfield a field so u can grab its text whenever u need it (in our
                                    // case in renderer)
    private HashMap<String, Color> words = new HashMap<>();

    TableExample() {
        f = new JFrame();
        // I changed the data a bit for my tests, take care of that.
        String data[][] = { { "101", "lala", "670000" }, { "101", "lala", "670000" }, { "102", "Jai", "780000" },
                { "101", "Sachin", "700000" } };
        String column[] = { "ID", "NAME", "SALARY" };
        JTable jt = new JTable();
        jt.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt); // You were not adding the sp into your panel, take care that next time.

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, column); // Create the model with our data.
        dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(column);
        jt.setModel(dtm);

        JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
        inputpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputpanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        textField = new JTextField();
        JButton button = new JButton("Highlight");

        button.addActionListener(e -> { // Button should only repaint the table (a.k.a read the renderer again).
            words.clear(); //Clear the map with the words
            String text = textField.getText(); // Grab the text.
            if (text.trim().length() > 0) {
                String[] splitPattern = text.split(","); //Split the words
                for (String s : splitPattern) {
                    words.put(s, getARandomColor()); //Put each word with a RANDOM color.
                }
            }
            jt.repaint();// Changing the table's renderer is bad on every button click, and no needed.
        });

        inputpanel.add(textField);
        inputpanel.add(button);
        jt.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CellHighlightRenderer()); // Add the renderer only 1 time.

        // I add sp here, not the table (if you want your table to actually have a
        // scrollpane)
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, inputpanel, sp);

        f.add(splitPane);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Hopefully you didnt forget this.
        f.setSize(300, 400);
        f.pack(); // Use pack() to the frame between set it visible.
        // f.setVisible(true); //setVisible to constructor is bad idea. I suggest you to
        // avoid that, and show your frame after its initiation.
    }

    class CellHighlightRenderer extends JTextField implements TableCellRenderer {
        public DefaultHighlighter high = new DefaultHighlighter();
        public DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlight_painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(
                Color.YELLOW);

        public CellHighlightRenderer() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            setHighlighter(high);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {

            setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
            setForeground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionForeground() : table.getForeground());

            setFont(table.getFont());
            setValue(value);
            int pos = 0;

            if (words.size() > 0) {
                for (String word : words.keySet()) {
                    while ((pos = value.toString().indexOf(word, pos)) >= 0) {
                        try {
                            highlight_painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(words.get(word));
                            // high.addHighlight(first, last, highlight_painter);
                            high.addHighlight(pos, pos + word.length(), highlight_painter);
                            pos += word.length();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        protected void setValue(Object value) {
            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        }
    }

    private Color getARandomColor() {
        return new Color((int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* *******THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT******* */
        /* All swing applications should run in their own thread, named EDT */
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TableExample te = new TableExample();
            te.f.setVisible(true); // Here, make it visisble
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't find what exactly i wanted. The code what ever i posted is already working, looks like you refactored it, thanks for that, being a beginner it's a learning for me. But the actual requirement is, if i enter a text with comma separated, those separated Strings has to be shown in different colors.

Comment: for example, if i enter lala,Jai as input, lala and Jai has to be highlighted in different colors. Hope i am clear.

Comment: yes, i get it now. Add this example to your original post. :P I will see what i can do..